# Localized ML Kit Image labels

Tags: firebase, firebase-mlkit

Is it possible to obtain labels from ML Kit Image Labeling in a given language?

I easily manage to get them in english...
but I need different languages... any suggestion?

In the docs I found this

> In addition the text description of each label that ML Kit returns, it also returns the label's Google Knowledge Graph entity ID. This ID is a string that uniquely identifies the entity represented by the label, and is the same ID used by the Knowledge Graph Search API. You can use this string to identify an entity across languages, and independently of the formatting of the text description.

Maybe it is possible to use a graph entity id to translate the label?
Or what else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

As the Firebase support told me via mail the day Feb 1, 2019

> Unfortunately at the moment it is not possible to use other languages for image labeling, however I have created a feature request for our engineering team to take a look at and consider for future releases. There's no telling on when this will be ready, but you can keep an eye on the [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) to be informed of the latest from Firebase.
>   On the other hand the Knowledge Graph entity ID can be used to find entities in the Google Knowledge Graph but at the moment it is not possible to connect these results with the image labeling in order to translate the label.

I firstly tryed to play with the Graph entity ID, in order to traslate the label description... but since i used the in-device Firebase library, i obtained some ID that Knowledge Graph wasn't able to recognize (for instance: *`Label: Flower, Confidence: 0.97793585, EntityID: /m/0c9ph5`*).

I ended up using a free translation API sevices (Yandex) wich is free for the first million translated character a day.